# Wordpress Contact form 7, fields in template.php - not validating correctly

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form-7, required, validating

I need to generate CF7 fields from php to make the form dynamic.

So instead of writing `<div>[text* your-name]</div>` and so on directly in wordpress, I have a template file that does that instead. **The problem is** that when doing so, the **validation is not working**. The fields are displayed correctly, but no fields are checked **when submitting**. If submitting, the data is however saved correctly.

WP ADMIN form tab:

```
[my_cf_template]
```

template.php

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(apply_filters("the_content", '[contact-form-7 id="115" title="Ruumide rent - booking"]')); ?>
```

functions.php

```
function cf_template_func(){

    $email = wpcf7_do_shortcode('[email* your-email]');
    $submit = wpcf7_do_shortcode( '[submit "Send"]' );

    $str = <<<HTML


    <div class="detailed-info">

        <label> Your E-mail*
        $email </label>

    </div>  
    $submit     
    HTML;
    return $str;
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_shortcode');

function custom_add_shortcode() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'my_cf_template', 'cf_template_func');
}
```

Comment: do you get any erro??

Comment: No errors/ When submitting, its submits the form correctly and pops up success message. So functionality is working but fields are not being validated. So theoretically if you don't fill any fields you can still submit and get success.

Comment: okay can you  provide url here??

Comment: Fortunately I cant, since it's only on my localhost. But what were you going to test? I could try myself

Comment: do you have Validation Filter??

Comment: I think you have to check this,http://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

Comment: no manually i havn't set any filters in regards of validation, all I have, is written above

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: okay,check and implement there is a method call `invalidate()` you have to focus on that

Comment: Okay so i tried this example on the link you shared. It still didnt do anything. It seems like submitting form doesnt even run any kind of validation functkion.  (when i tested the example while putting shortcodes in admin, it worked so I know I didnt make mistakes, but mistake is still somewhere else). So looks like wpcf7_validate_email* didnt even run

Comment: check console do you have any error in console.log ?

Comment: No errors, and network logs shows "{"mailSent":true,"into":"#wpcf7-f115-o1","captcha":null,"message":"Thank you for your message. It has been sent."}"

Comment: Maybe im initializing something too early or too late in my php files? I tried to use different hooks but no positive results.

Comment: Is this your custom template for CF7??

Comment: Yes. Custom template where im basically defining all the layout of the form. Then using that [my_cf_template] shortcode to "require" all the layout from php to cf7 admin. It looks to me like it doesnt validate the fields because they dont directly exist in the wp-admin, So if i could maybe find a way to manually in php set all the fields that need to be validated i think it should work. I just dont know how to